# I am struggling with trying to use the Where() method in C# to turn a string into its camel case, code does not do anything

Tags: c#, list, where-clause, camelcasing

as mentioned in the title I am trying to turn a given string with spaces in between words into a camel case format, for example: "camel case" becomes "camelCase".

My method is to try and turn the string into an array of characters, and then check if the previous character was a space, but I am stuck on the part where I am using a Where() method in order to check every character:

*str = new string(str.Where(x => Array.IndexOf(str.ToCharArray(), x) - 1 != ' ').ToArray());*

This just returns the original string without doing anything.

Any help would be appreciated, and maybe you could suggest a better way of doing it too, after all, we're all in this together right?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version with a linq select

```
public static string ToCamelCase(string value)
{
    int n = 0;
    return string.Join("",
        value.ToLower()
        .Split(' ')
        .Select(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t) ? ""
            : n++ == 0
                ? t
                : $"{t.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()}{t.Substring(1)}"
    );
}
```

Comment: Edited to handle multi whitespaces between words

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to do it without regular expressions I would just use that.

Here's one way:

```
Regex
    .Replace(str, @"\s+([^\s])", ma => ma.Groups[1].Value.ToUpperInvariant())
    .TrimEnd()
```

This will replace any sequence of one or more whitespace characters that are followed by a non-whitespace character with the uppercase version of that non-whitespace character.

Essentially it will remove all whitespace (except for at the very end, thus the `.TrimEnd()` method), and it will try to convert the first character following each sequence of whitespace to uppercase.

Example code:

```
string input = "locate the next person of age 50 or above";
string output = Regex
    .Replace(input, @"\s+([^\s])", ma => ma.Groups[1].Value.ToUpperInvariant())
    .Trim();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output:

```
locateTheNextPersonOfAge50OrAbove
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple loop.

```
public static string ToCamelCase(this string value) 
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    bool nextUpper = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        if (value[i] == ' ')
            nextUpper = true;
        else
        {
            if (nextUpper)
                result += value[i].ToString().ToUpper();
            else
                result += value[i].ToString().ToLower();
            nextUpper = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because there are 2 `c`s in your string, so Array.IndexOf() will always return position of first `c`. Maybe some LINQ magician can fix this with proper LINQ, but if you don't mind using other methods, a `StringBuilder` and a foreach-loop through `str` can achieve the quest.

Something like:

```
string str = "camel case";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
bool pickedSpace = false;

foreach (char c in str)
{
  if (c == ' ')
    pickedSpace = true;
  else if (pickedSpace) {
    sb.Append(Char.ToUpper(c));
    pickedSpace = false;
  } else {
    sb.Append(c);
  }
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

You can also check if the last element in the `StringBuilder` is space, then remove it and `ToUpper()` next char to join instead of using a boolean, for less overhead.